# Why do we want to diagonalize a compact self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

I am reading *Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces, and Partial Differential Equations* by Haim Brezis, and the theorem proving the existence of spectral decompositions of compact self-adjoint operators in Hilbert spaces is prefaced with the following.

> Our last statement is a *fundamental* result. It asserts that every compact self-adjoint
> operator may be *diagonalized* in some suitable basis.

This is the theorem in question.

> Theorem 6.11. Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and let $T$ be a compact selfadjoint operator. Then there exists a Hilbert basis composed of eigenvectors of $T$.

My question is a naïve (and compound) one: what is the motivation for considering this, and what does this get us? I saw that it allows us to prove that all Hilbert spaces have the approximation property, but I'm wondering what other results in functional analysis/PDEs we get from it.

Comment: One (short) answer is found by considering the finite-dimensional case, which essentially reduces to matrices. There, a diagonal matrix is considerably easier to understand at first gland than a random matrix, so it's very convenient to be able to choose a basis where your linear transformation is represented by a diagonal transformation.

Comment: If you like differential equations, then google for Sturm -Liouville equations.